# How to approximate 1/3 by only add/subtracting powers of 2

Tags: puzzle

How approximate $\frac{1}{3}$ up to four significant digits by using only $\pm2^n$ where $n$ is a negative integer.

Preliminary attempt/example:
$$0.33\approx0.25+0.0625=0.3125$$
$$=2^{-2}+2^{-4}$$

Comment: Note that $\frac13 = \frac{1}{1+2}$. Have you heard about geometric series?

Comment: You should convert it into binary system.

Comment: If you want positive terms, you can use binary representation.

Comment: Sorry guys, that was a bit of a dumb question in hindsight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The series
$$\frac12 - \frac1{2^2} + \frac1{2^3} - \cdots + \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n} + \cdots$$
converges to $\dfrac13$.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from where you left off, the sequence $$2^{-2}+2^{-4}+2^{-6}+...$$ converges to $\frac 13$ using the formula for a geometric series